# A git dependency in package.json errors out with "access denied(publickey)"?

Tags: git

Originally I had this in my package.json on line#3 of dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "auth0-js": "^9.13.4",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "felix.ui": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/felix/felix.ui.git#1.2.3"
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
...
```

It did not work and errored with while yarn install.

```
git@bitbucket.org: Permission Denied(publickey)
```

I changed it to the https format, and it worked.

```
"felix.ui": "https://mygitusername:mygitpassword@bitbucket.org/felix/felix.ui.git#1.2.3",
```

I have 2 ssh key pairs: one for my public git profile, the other for my org/work-related stuff. This is Windows 10. Config file(i.e. .ssh/config) goes like the following:

```
# Github (default)
  Host gh
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

# Bitbucket (secondary)
  Host bb
  HostName bitbucket.org
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work
```

Comment: ... and, what's your actual question?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted your `id_rsa_work` private key to be used, you should configure Git to use the `.ssh/config` `Bitbucket` entry

```
git config --global url."Bitbucket:".insteadOf git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/
```

That way, the ssh URL becomes:

```
git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/felix/felix.ui.git#1.2.3
# to
Bitbucket:felix/felix.ui.git#1.2.3
```

Comment: I will try this out as well.

Comment: @nihal OK. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I used https repo URL with credentials and it did the trick.

Thanks for the answers.